# How can I add some static IP address at IPv6 for Windows 2012 DHCP server?

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp, ipv6

I would like to add some static IP address to my Windows 2012 DHCP server. I have tried to pair the IP address with its MAC address. At IPv4 it works, but how can do it at IPv6? Could anybody link a detailed description?

In DHCP I have tried to add a new reservation under the ipv6 scope, but a DUID/IAID is necessary. The following description says that the ipconfig show what is the DUID and IAID of computer. I ran that task, but I didn't find anywhere. How can I see the DUID/IAID of the Windows7 and Linux Debian clients?

http://ipv6friday.org/blog/2011/12/dhcpv6/

Comment: Do you really need DHCP for your IPv6 addresses, its usually not necessary thanks to [SLAAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Stateless_address_autoconfiguration_.28SLAAC.29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can use `ipconfig /all` to find the DUID & IAID:

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::40d5:d138:125e:4478%21(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 352845825
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-E0-CE-11-50-E5-49-C8-14-AA
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

On Linux, its going to depend on your DHCPv6 client.  By default, IPv6 does not use DHCP, so you need to enable it explicitly on all of your clients.
For example, by default, the [wide DHCPv6 client](http://wide-dhcpv6.sourceforge.net/) stores the DUID in the file:

```
/var/lib/dhcpv6/dhcp6c_duid
```